# Change attribute of another object B within object A in Python

Tags: python, list, attributes, self, object-oriented-database

Suppose I have two classes of objects, A and B. Both are linked together in a database. We have an Event and a series of Actions associated with each event, and some attributes of each.

```
class Event(object):
    def __init__(self, ...some irrelevant attributes...):
        self.attributes = attributes
        self.actions = []

    def add_action(self, action):
        self.actions.append = action

class Action(object):
    def __init__(self, ...some irrelevant attributes...):
        self.attributes = attributes
        self.event = None

    def add_event(self, event):
        self.event = event
        # I would like to make self part of event.actions as above
```

When I call

```
event = Event(...)
```

in `Action(...)` to add Action to an event in a database, is there a legal way in Python to make the Action itself (self) part of Event's list of Actions?

Answer (score 0):

Just call `add_action()`

```
    def add_event(self, event):
        self.event = event
        # I would like to make self part of event.actions as above
        event.add_action(self)
```

Also, you have a mistake in `add_action()`. It should call the `append()` method, not assign to it.

```
    def add_action(self, action):
        self.actions.append(action)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should call `add_action` with `self`. you should also change the way you append to your list of actions. the `append` attribute of a list is a `function`

```
class Event(object):
    def __init__(self, attributes):
        self.attributes = attributes
        self.actions = []

    def add_action(self, action):
        self.actions.append(action)


class Action(object):
    def __init__(self, attributes):
        self.attributes = attributes
        self.event = None

    def add_event(self, event):
        self.event = event
        event.add_action(self)
```